# Install GlusterFS on CentOS 8 not working

Tags: vmware-workstation, centos8, glusterfs

I am trying to install GlusterFS on CentOS 8 Vmware workstation, i am on a bridged network but everytime i attempy to download it i get this messsage. Is there another way to do this or to fix this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

at time of this post Gluster 8 (https://www.gluster.org/release-schedule/) is the current maintained version. So to install it you would do

> dnf -y install centos-release-gluster8

Please note that you can find other versions in the extras repository which, as you see above, is enabled.